# Collect parts of duplicated elements in a list and merge them in just one element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a huge Excel file which contains properties and their values.
The problem is as follows: Some properties are able to contain multiple values.

Example:

```
list = ['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'd=4', 'd=5', 'd=6', 'e=7']
```

Should be:

```
list2 = ['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'd=4,5,6', 'e=7']
```

The elements are strings with a variable length and they are seperated by a '='.

This is how i generate the list out of the Excel file:

```
#for each row in the excel file.
for rows in range(DATA_ROW, sheet.nrows):
#generate a list with all properties.
for cols in range(sheet.ncols):
    #if the propertie is not emty 
    if str(sheet.cell(PROPERTIE_ROW,cols).value) is not '':
        proplist.append(sheet.cell(PROPERTIE_ROW,cols).value + '=' + str(sheet.cell(rows,cols).value) + '\n')
```

I gave it a try but that didn't work very well ...

```
last_item = ''
new_list = []
#find and collect multiple values.
for i, item in enumerate(proplist):
#if the propertie is already in the list
if str(item).find(last_item) is not -1:
    #just copy the value and append it to the propertie
    new_list.insert(i, propertie);
else:
    #slize the string in propertie and value
    pos = item.find('=')
    propertie = item[0:pos+1]
    value = item[pos+1:len(item)]
    #save the propertie
    last_item = propertie
    #append item
    new_list.append(item)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when there are duplicate key *and* values? Say `['a=7', 'a=7']`? Should that be merged to `['a=7,7']`? Should order be preserved?

Comment: Technically this won't happen. But if it does, the duplicate can be ignored. The order is  important and should be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you could probably use a `defaultdict` for this sort of thing:

```
from collections import defaultdict
orig = ['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'd=4', 'd=5', 'd=6', 'e=7']
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in orig:
    k,v = item.split('=',1)
    d[k].append(v)

new = ['{0}={1}'.format(k,','.join(v)) for k,v in d.items()]
print(new)  #['a=1', 'c=3', 'b=2', 'e=7', 'd=4,5,6']
```

---

I suppose that if order does matter, you could use an `OrderedDict` + `setdefault` but it really isn't as pretty:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
orig = ['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'd=4', 'd=5', 'd=6', 'e=7']
d = OrderedDict()
for item in orig:
    k,v = item.split('=',1)
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)

new = ['{0}={1}'.format(k,','.join(v)) for k,v in d.items()]
print new # ['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'd=4,5,6', 'e=7']
```

Comment: I have no clue whether this is a good idea, but I created an OrderedDefaultDict as follows: `class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict, defaultdict):` with `__init__` defined as `def __init__(self, default):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, default);
        OrderedDict.__init__(self)`.  It seems to work but I have no experience in multiple inheritance.  I just cross my fingers and hope that `OrderedDict` and `defaultdict` override different methods of `dict`.  But I thought I'd at least mention the idea.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- I've done that before too actually.  In reality though, It's probably easier to just subclass `OrderedDict` and put the "default" behavior into `__missing__`.